# Oracle SQL get list of unique dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Alright, I'm stumped here. I'm trying to get a list of only unique dates from the following table:

`SALES(OUTLET_NUMBER, EMP_NUMBER, CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, SALE_DATE, SALE_TIME, quantity)`

But when I try the statement:

```
SELECT SALE_DATE 
  FROM sales 
GROUP BY 
       SALE_DATE;
```

It does not remove already existing dates.

```
SALE_DATE   
20-MAR-14  
19-MAR-14  
20-MAR-14  
20-MAR-14  
01-DEC-13  
19-MAR-14
```

This is the output from oracle.  Why does it sill display 3 versions of 20-MAR-14 and what can I do to get it to give me only unique dates?

Comment: Truncate the date to GROUP by year,month,day or whatever interval you need.Because it also stores time.

Comment: group by trunc(SALE_DATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, the `date` data type rather misleadingly also contains a time.  The easiest way to do what you want is using `trunc()`, although you could also format the date as a string using `to_char()`.

Try this:

```
SELECT trunc(SALE_DATE) as sale_date
FROM sales
GROUP BY trunc(SALE_DATE)
ORDER BY trunc(SALE_DATE);
```

Comment: Is this considered a feature or a bug in oracle?

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick.  It makes sense now why it was acting like there was 6 different dates because technically there are.

Comment: @Mihai, neither a bug nor a feature, just a quirk - the datatype should have been called `DATETIME` but was instead called `DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

The `date` type in Oracle also stores the time. When you print out the `date`s you've queried they are transformed to strings according to your default date format. Since it seems to be `dd-mon-yy`, you don't see their time part, and it seems like you have duplicates.

You could, for instnace, remove the time part by using the `trunc` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRUNC(sale_date) FROM sales
```